# How can I create spoiler text?

Tags: html, css

How can I make spoiler text on a website with HTML and CSS?

What I was is, text that is black with black background, but when hovered over, makes the black text turn white, making it visible.

Like this:

```html
<span style="color: black; background: black;">test</span>

<p>Then when hovered over</p>

<span style="color: white; background: black;">test</span>
```

Comment: [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)

Comment: So like `<span style="color: black; background: black; span:hover { color: white}">test</span>` ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```css
.spoiler, .spoiler2, .spoiler a, .spoiler2 a{ 
  color: black; 
  background-color: black;
}

.spoiler:hover, .spoiler:hover a {
  color: white;
}

.spoiler2:hover, .spoiler2:hover a { 
 background-color:white; 
}
```

```html
<span class="spoiler" >test <a href='#'>with link</a> </span>

<p>Then when hovered over <a href='#'> outside link</a> </p>

<span class="spoiler2"> other test <a href='#'>with link</a> </span>
```

Comment: You can also change the `background-color` property to white, this would look like the more common spoiler tags

Comment: How would one modify this to handle the common case of containing other tags (e.g. links) that have been styled with other colors on them?

Answer (score 95):

The `<details>` HTML tag was designed specifically for this purpose. Here is the example from the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details). The tag is supported on all current browsers, but not on IE.

```html
<details>
    <summary>Details</summary>
    Something small enough to escape casual notice.
</details>
```

Comment: Edge supports this tag since version 79 released in January 2020 (https://caniuse.com/#search=details). IE still doesn't support it.

Comment: Wow, so simple yet effective. And IE is End of Life so that concern will fade over time...

Answer (score 5):

Similar to the spoiler in [Disqus](https://disqus.com) comments.

```css
.spoiler{
  background-color: gray;
  color: transparent;
  user-select: none;
}

.spoiler:hover{
  background-color: inherit;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<h3>In the movie, <span class="spoiler">the hero kills his wife.</span></h3>
```

Comment: Would it require much code changes to reveal spoiler after click? (or to make it look like moving noise like on telegram?)

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki No, just replace :hover with :active

Comment: Love it! Thank you! Changed code: https://codepen.io/gwpl/pen/BamRzpe

Answer (score 0):

I have seen spoilers on forums (including my own) that are not just text with the background color changed.

They have the content hidden until you click a show/hide toggle button.

I want to add a section to a site that doesn't show up by default to save space.

https://jsfiddle.net/clarle/bY7m4/

That seems like it will meet my needs.

#### HTML

```html
<div class="forum-post">
    <a href="#hide" class="hide btn" id="hide">Show spoiler</a>
    <a href="#show" class="show btn" id="show">Hide spoiler</a>
    <div class="spoiler">
      <p class="spoiler-content">People die when they are killed!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.spoiler {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: none;
}

.hide:target + .show {
  display: inline;
}

.hide:target {
  display: none;
}

.hide:target ~ .spoiler {
  display: inline;
}

/* Just for prettiness, not actually needed */

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.btn {
  padding: 4px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  *margin-left: .3em;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333333;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  *background-color: #E6E6E6;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #E6E6E6);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#FFFFFF), to(#E6E6E6));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #E6E6E6);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #E6E6E6);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF, #E6E6E6);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
  *border: 0;
  border-color: #E6E6E6 #E6E6E6 #BFBFBF;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-bottom-color: #A2A2A2;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
          border-radius: 4px;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#ffe6e6e6', GradientType=0);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
  *zoom: 1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.forum-post {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.spoiler-content {
  padding: 15px;
}
```