# Make top left/right border radius not change when element is shrunk?

Tags: css, border

Have a rather simple spoiler code for my website. It has sort of large border radii, which is fine when the element is expanded, but not so much when shrunk. Is there some way I can make the bottom border radii just go to 0px when its shrunk, or is that just not a thing with CSS?

And I would, yes, like it to be a CSS solution. It's no real problem for me to have to shrink the border radius, but y'know, might as well try to not if its possible.

I am not sure how to make the javascript my code uses work on stackoverflow (it just gives me errors), so [here](http://prntscr.com/dy5cdi) is a screenshot of what it looks like expanded.

```css
.panel {
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 22px 22px 10px 10px;
  font-family:arial;
}

.panel>h3 {
  font-size:14px;
  background-color:#820D1A;
  color:#ededed;
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
  text-align:left;
  padding:4px;
  padding-left:20px;
  margin:0px;
  border-radius: 21px 21px 0px 0px;
}

.panel>div {
  padding:4px;
}

.panel>div:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
   <h3>(PARAM1)<span style="font-size:10px;margin-left:6px;">(Click to toggle)</span></h3>
  <div style="display:none">(PARAM2)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there supposed to be a non hidden `DIV` under the other?

Comment: What do you mean...? What happens is that you click on the <h3>, and the .panel>div swaps to display:block, as all spoiler boxes work. I removed the script I was using because it's not relevant to the border-radius of the closed box, and it kept erroring me when I tried to put it in here. Not worth the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eh, after messing around I came to the answer that no, it isn't possible. I just resolved to decrease the top border radii by 5 pixels (making them 17px) so that it'd look normal open or closed.

Thank you to everyone who put forth some help, though~

Answer (score 0):

```css
.panel {
 background-color: #820D1A;
 border: 1px solid gray;
 border-radius: 22px 22px 10px 10px;
 font-family: arial;
}

.panel>h3 {
  font-size:14px;
  color:#ededed;
  text-align:left;
  padding-left:20px;
  margin:5px;
}

.panel>div {
  padding:4px;
 background-color: #FFF;
}

.panel>div:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
   <h3>(PARAM1)<span style="font-size:10px;margin-left:6px;">(Click to toggle)</span></h3>
   <div style="display: none">(PARAM2)</div>
</div>
```

Does this look closer to what you are trying to achieve? There were two padding rules on the `h3` and I was wondering why you have a background on there as well? Would this not work with your Javascript?

Comment: The h3 had 2 padding rules to indent the text more. And yes, the background colour was intentional. It's so that .panel>div has the right background colour as opposed to having the red just kinda awkwardly shoved in there. Have you not worked with spoiler boxes before? Not to be hostile-- I'm genuinely curious, because this seems very obvious to me. I don't understand a point of view where it isn't obvious.

Comment: Oh indeed I have. I use the `Bootstrap` framework now because it's already included in the markup, but it is good to know. You could actually use what I provided to create your Spoiler box (I have not heard this term before).  You don't really HAVE to use javascript unless you want to have a transition of sorts. Here is a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28615544/how-to-create-spoiler-text) to this same sort of question on StackOverflow.

Comment: The difference between that and what I'm doing is that this is a clickable box, not just a hover thing.

Comment: So you change the state from onHover to onClick. AS long as you got it figured out.